# Bicycle in Tokyo Monorail

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, tokyo, bicycles, hnd

[Tokyo Monorail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Monorail) is a convenient line between [Haneda Airport](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo_Haneda_Airport) and [Shinbashi](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo/Shinbashi) in central [Tokyo](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo).

Let's say I brought my bicycle to Japan and want to reach central Tokyo quickly and easily. Can I just ride Tokyo Monorail with my bicycle along?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with no additional fee, but you must fold your bicycle and put it into a bicycle bag.

[Tokyo Monorail's official website](http://www.tokyo-monorail.co.jp/tickets/type.html) says:

> 自転車はそのまま車内に持ち込むことはできません。
>   持ち込む場合には、自転車を解体、もしくは折りたたみ、専用の袋(輪行袋)に収納した上でご乗車ください。

Translation:

> You can not enter the train with a bicycle as-is.
>   If you want to bring it, you must disassemble the bicycle (front wheel, or fold it if it is a foldable bicycle) and put it into a bicycle bag made for that purpose, then enter the train.

[image: Bicycle bag]

Article about this bag, in Japanese: [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/輪行袋](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BC%AA%E8%A1%8C%E8%A2%8B)

If you had your bicycle when landing at Haneda, chances are you have such a bag already. Otherwise, you can buy one for between 1300 and 10,000 yen.

Comment: @JoeBlow: The idea would be to plan ahead bring the bag with you. If you had your bicycle when landing at Haneda, chances are you have such a bag already.

Comment: true enough about flying

Comment: @JoeBlow The proliferation of collapsible bikes in this country is probably the reason for this rule, OTHERWISE the answer would be no. Bicycle bags go for only ～￥1300 as well.

Comment: OK, good one!!!

Comment: It would be useful to add that "disassembling" means removing the front wheel as the minimum. By the way, the bag on the picture is exactly that type where only one wheel is removed.